# Inverted pendulum with reaction wheel

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I'm a little confused about the equations of motion of the reaction wheel pendulum. It is used in self balancing bicycles - see vide link in comments (I can't add another link here due to low rep). Or search Murata boy for a commercial product.

I am fairly sure my equations are correct but I have seen them represented differently.

[image]

If I look at this from a simplistic point of view and initially IGNORE the torque, $\tau$, due to the reaction wheel. Then:

$$Mgl\sin\theta = J\ddot{\theta}  \tag1$$ or $$J\ddot{\theta} - Mgl\sin\theta = 0  \tag2$$

To keep things simple, M is the total mass and J is the combined inertia of the bar and wheel. Am I correct so far?

Now, to my mind, the torque, $\tau = J_r\ddot{\theta}_r$, opposes the system from falling (that's the point of it anyway). So,

$$Mgl\sin\theta - J_r\ddot{\theta}_r = J\ddot{\theta} \tag3$$ or $$J\ddot{\theta} - Mgl\sin\theta + J_r\ddot{\theta}_r = 0  \tag4$$

Is the above correct? If so, then my confusion is because I have seen it expressed in Karl Astrom's book - The Reaction Wheel Pendulum - as (I've re-arranged here from his book). Note the '+':

$$J\ddot{\theta} + Mgl\sin\theta + J_r\ddot{\theta}_r = 0  \tag5$$

Of course I am not saying the book is wrong but I can't see why mine is different. His angles are shown differently but I would have thought that the end result is the same. His convention is as follows:

[image: Karl Astrom convention]

My other confusion is related to motor torque - assume there is a motor turning the reaction wheel. Is this motor torque (which is $kI$ - torque constant x current) equal or opposite in sign to the torque created by the reaction wheel. i.e. Is it:

$$J_r\ddot{\theta}_r = kI  \tag6$$
Or
$$J_r\ddot{\theta}_r = -kI  \tag7$$

I think my final equation for motion is (by combining (4) and (6)):

$$J\ddot{\theta} - Mgl\sin\theta = -kI \tag8$$

Would really like some insight here. Thanks.

Comment: Please describe the physical situation.  I don't know what a reaction wheel pendulum is, so I stopped reading.

Comment: @garyp - it is for a self balancing bicycle. This video shows it well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEctw-TUCcs

Comment: am working on the same project did you find anything intersting
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUVtObDFFWY
here some one how work just like your proj